# Как создать расширение для браузера на Python. Это вообще возможно?

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, google-chrome

Появилась у меня гениальная идея - сделать заметки в виде расширения для Chrome. Обладаю лишь знаниями Python, CSS и HTML. Есть ли какие нибудь библиотеки для этого на Python?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать простое Python (бессерверное) расширение на Chrome на Python. [тык](https://pythonspot.com/en/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/)
Но это скорее костыль чем решение, т.к. ввш код будет компилироваться в JS благодоря [Rapydscript](http://www.rapydscript.com/)

Так же можете использовать [pyjs](http://pyjs.org/)